# Graphing Data over time with a line graph

Tags: python

So I need to graph on what day there where followers using a line graph. But nothing shows up heres my code

```
def follower_timeplot(self,g,node):
    dic={node: list(g.predecessors(node))}
    lst=[]
    D={}
    for item in dic[node]:
        lst.append(g[item][node]['Timecreated'])
    D = {x:lst.count(x) for x in lst}
    df= pd.Series(D, name='DateValue')
    df.index.name = 'Date'
    df.columns=['cnt'] 
    df.reset_index()
    #print(df)
    plt.plot(x='Date', y='cnt')
```

this is a method that takes in a graph from networkx and looks a certian node and any indegree "Timecreated" is put in a dateframe then graphed.

So in short i need a line graph of the people following exaple date in the data frame looks like

```
Date
2011-01-18    1
2016-09-30    2
2015-10-07    1
2018-05-08    1
2018-11-18    1
2013-02-05    2
2018-06-04    2
2018-11-17    1
2018-11-15    2
2018-08-22    2
2012-12-14    1
2018-03-13    1
2013-05-02    1
2017-11-19    1
2017-06-11    2
2017-12-17    2
```

Comment: Is this all of your code? You are missing `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `pandas` plot function instead. Also remember to add `plt.show()` to your code.

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: how would i space the graph out more its only by year

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If my answer does help you please consider to accept the question (green tick) and/or upvote. I think you should ask another question for what you mention in this comment and show the graph that results from your code and explain in detail what you expect.